# Always return else part wheras my condition true

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, return

```
class test:
def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    for i in nums:
        if i == target:
            return nums.index(target)
        else:
            return -1
```

why it's always return -1, whereas my condition is true

Comment: Your loop always returns during the first iteration – either the index 0 or the fallback -1. Move the "found nothing" ``return -1`` *outside* of the loop, after it has checked every item.

Comment: move the last line to outside the for loop, and remove the `else`.

Answer (score 1):

If `first element != target` you return `-1`, you need return `-1` at end of for like below:

```
def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
    for i in nums:
        if i == target:
            return nums.index(target)
    return -1
```

You can use `enumerate` and change `for` like below:

```
for idx, num in enumerate(nums):
   if num == target:
       return idx
return -1
```